# SImple server to run program and return result

Tags: linux, bash, netcat, client-server

I am attempting to create a minimal local listen server that takes an input request, pipes the input to a program and then returns the result of the command.

What I have at the moment is the program which works like

```
echo "input" | scriptProgram
output
```

And I am attempting to use netcat to act as a listen server like

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 -l 1234 -kv -e scriptProgram
```

And test its output by using another ncat a a client

```
echo "input" | ncat 127.0.0.1 1234 -v
ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.1:1234.
ncat: 6 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 4.71 seconds.
```

And I don't see the output from the program on either terminal
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, or have any advise?

Comment: It's possible I'm a bit out of my depth, but I'm unclear on what your question is.  What, specifically, are you trying to do?  Sometimes tunnelvision gets you so focused on some little thing that you miss a huge number of equal or better solutions because they're not in that tiny area you're looking.

Comment: I am attempting to make a command line program into a simple server. I am using netcat as it seems to promise to be able to do that, however somewhere along the route back the response is getting lost.